# apache2 authenticated users list

Tags: php, apache2, basic-authentication

I have apache2 set up with basic auth, I want to display on my php web site a list of all authenticated users that sent an HTTP request the last 10 minutes. What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: PHP will not have access to the Apache logs, so cannot *easily* do this without introducing large security holes. One option would be to have the PHP files write an access log in `/var/www`, use `.htaccess` to block direct access to the file, and create a page that reads from that log file ... 

Comment: You can access the name of the authorized used via `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` (depending on how PHP is integrated into the web server, it might need additional configuration to pass those along) - so that way you could log any requests for PHP scripts at least. But if there is any chance a user might access f.e. an asset like an image or video outside of a script, or any static .html page, those would not be counted (unless you would be willing to redirect all those to a PHP script as well, then that script would have to read the file content and pass it on to the client.)

Comment: I ended up with the simple solution of cron job every x minutes to parse access.log of web server and create an output file of users successfully logged in the last X minutes. javascript then GETs every x minutes the list. Note, I only have like 20 users on this page usually a handful on-line, we just need to know who is in, working on stuff. This is not a public web-site thus this hackery for solution. Site running on an RPI, cronjob only spikes the cpu to 20% for 5 seconds to figure this out.